# Angular Material 6 Disable Ripple on Checkbox and Radio button

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-material, angular6

I've got a situation where there are radio buttons up against the edge of a container that is nested several levels deep, with overflow auto.  The Angular matererial radio button has the ripple effect, which gets clipped.  Rather than reworking the whole thing, I was going to turn off the ripple, with disableRipple.  This works for click, but does not seem to work when tabbing between components, as illustrated in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxfmmz) and as shown in the screenshot below, where I tabbed to, rather than clicked, Option 1 on top. I tried updating the css to display: none, but then there's no visual cue, at all, when the focus changes.  It seems to me the ripple effect should an overlay to avoid clipping problems, but that's not how it works. So is there a way to turn it off for both tab and click?

[image]

Comment: It seems like they don't want to support removing the ripple animation on focus.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is the ripple element that is "rippling" when you keyboard to the radio button, technically it's more of a focus/touch indicator than a click-ripple. Without it you can't tell where your focus is. The radio button click itself doesn't have that problem because it gets filled in so there is a visual indication of the change. I can't see any way around this other than overriding the div.mat-ripple-element background-color property. I'm not sure I'd personally want to do that because of the impact on focus indication. Do you really need to hide the overflow? Why not use `overflow: visible`?

Comment: (Thought I had responded on this already.)  The issue is that the components are right up against the edge of a nested set of divs, and changing to overflow:visible on all of them affects other things I'd rather not have to rework.   In the end, I just admitted defeat and added a margin to the components in the so that it the halo looks right when tabbing through.  It doesn't look exactly like we want it, but is more in keeping with the material design style, anyway.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old post but thought I can help someone. You can just add:

```
.mat-ripple-element{
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything in Angular 7.2.

Comment: I know this is an old post but put it in styles.css

Comment: I had a problem with that, because my checkbox was at the very bottom of modal dialog, so unwanted scrollbar appeared. The intended class, which I had to assign this style to, was `mat-ripple`. But, anyway, thanks for great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Without overwritting Angular materials by using ::ng-deep, it's not possible to disable ripple effect. For example for slide toggle button:

```
::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-ripple {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the size of the ripple.

```css
   :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(80% - 10px);
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```